# Setting group and owner of a file in obj-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsfilemanager, rights

I am trying to change group and owner of a file in a cocoa application and was planning to use `setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:` method of `NSFileManager`

However I was wondering how to get possible values for `NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID` and `NSFileOwnerAccountID`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name of the particular user or group, you can use `getpwnam(3)` and `getgrnam(3)` to obtain the corresponding ids.

If you want to iterate over the list of users or groups, you can use `getpwent(3)` and `getgrent(3)`.